# Replace markup in file without writing new file

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, rendering

I have HTML markup in a file. I intend picking out that markup, replacing the placeholders in it per the data set, and returning a merged string. I could simply use a server-side template (I did previously) but cannot afford it now as some client-side code requires same markup for front end stuff i.e code beyond `public/`. Presently, the server just hangs whenever it runs into the exec function and throws nor console.errors nothing.

The code looks like this

```
 var availableFoodsString = "",
regexCb = function (dataSet, flag, indexPage) {
    return function(match, $1, index) {
        if (indexPage == undefined && dataSet["username"] != undefined) {
            dataSet["username_search"] = dataSet["username"];
        }

        if (dataSet[$1] != undefined) return dataSet[$1];

        else if (flag == "EMPTY") return "";
        else if (flag == "MATCH") return match;
    }
}; 


foodsModel.find({availableToday: true}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;

    docs.forEach(function (doc) {
        doc = doc.toObject();
        doc.image = "/images/food/" + doc.name + ".jpg";

        var template = /(<div class="food-menu">(\s*.*)*<\/div>)/gi.exec(fs.readFileSync("public/index.html").toString())[0]
        availableFoodsString += template.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/gi, regexCb(doc))
    });
});
```

In essence, I need `availableFoodsString` at the end of the day as an additional value to be rendered to another placeholder i.e render({available: availableFoodsString}).

The public/index.html is a normal HTML with this somewhere in between

{{name}}

{{price}}

add to cart

So, some jQuery code also needs this much coveted markup at some point after DOM is fully loaded, while `doc` from the model contain name and price filler variables.

The `foodsModel.find()` function is async, yes, but it is called inside the http.createServer function by the database opening connection callback so the variable is definitely loaded at that point.

I have seen some other solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498059/replace-regular-expression-in-text-file-with-file-contents-using-node-js) and related questions but they all either involve imploring some external module from npm, or writing a new file from the matched markup, before replacing and merging into the desired variable. I know there has to be a way to achieve this without any of those.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to recreate a client-side framework like AngularJS or Knockout.

Comment: The application is already complete. Just a recent feature inclusion required dumping the template on the landing page. You'll agree that reconstructing from the beginning with any of those features is an overkill akin to killing a fly with a sledgehammer. If it comes to the worst, I can resort to leaving them in separate files and use AJAX to load the template on the front end. I just thought I could find something more elegant.

Comment: @adam0101 * You'll agree that reconstructing
from the beginning with any of those with any of those frameworks* is what I meant. Not "features". I couldn't edit the comment since SO's edit buttons use Ajax which doesn't work on my mobile, regrettably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had to do with my regex. The second parenthesis was guilty of something called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Which means the match was greedy in a way that put the interpreter through hell i.e. taking back more than needed instead of inversely giving back as needed. I knocked up a few spots on the regex and everything works seamlessly now.

The old code stayed the same, just the regex changed from this:

`/(<div class="food-menu">(\s*.*)*<\/div>)/gi`

to this:

`/(<div class="food-menu">(\s+.*)+<\/div>)/g`

For some reason, the previous regex appeared to match the file string seamlessly, first time I tested it, but was brutally unforgiving once I plugged it in real code.